# AD5231 Digital Pot programming/ Hardware issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

I am trying to use the AD5231 Digital potentiometer in a school project. However, I am having a lot of trouble with it. It's supposed to be connected to raspberry pi (model 2 B+) and I've trying to speak to it via SPI

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this. This is the following code I am using to try and speak to the device (I'm using Python)

```
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 10000
spi.writebytes([0xC0, 0x00, 0x00])
```

However, no matter what I do, I am constantly reading 75kohms from terminal A to terminal B, where B is grounded and A is a NC. I'm not sure whether I should be feeding any voltage to the wiper resistance. The rest of the hardware should be set up properly as I have redone it a few times to make sure.

Comment: at every step, check whether you have an error. I don't know your SpiDev library, so it's hard to tell you how to do that. Also, make sure you've configured the SPI bus correctly. SPI has something called *polarity*, which defines clock edge and signal polarity. Try out whether the pins you're using are actually the pins used to send your SPI commands.

Comment: Depending on the AD5231 version, you should read 10K, 50K or 100K between the A and B terminals - they are the ends of the resistance element.  The resistance between terminal W (the wiper/moving contact) and terminal A or terminal B should vary depending on the values you write to the device.  The resistance between B and W should be near Zero when you write Zero to the device.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had connected the spi ends to an oscilloscope and everything looked fine. I was able to see the data and read it on the scope. I tried to measure the resistance from W to b, again it remains constant.

Comment: Im not sure if there’s a something that’s blocking inside the IC, or if I should place resistors before supplying the power source or not. I’m really lost to be honest and it’s very frustrating. Not much examples online only the data sheet really.

Comment: According to the datasheet, the command you are using `C0` will left shift the RDAC data by 1 position (increasing the resistance). but if you are using a 10k device, 7.5k will already have the msb set and little will occur. Try using code `B0` to actually set an arbitrary value. You could also try command `01` which will restore the EEMEM contents which (if unchanged from factory) will set it up for midscale.

Comment: I am very surprised that your spi library does not have arguments to define the *mode* (or perhaps you are simply not using them). In my experience, SPI interfaces have to be individually crafted for each device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’ll look into that as well. Also, have the 100K digipot

Comment: @PeterSmith This solved the problem

Comment: @PeterSmith  Please convert your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the mode helped us properly communicate to the digipots. Thanks Peter Smith for your answer.